# how to split a single list value in python which is separated by comma

Tags: python, regex

```
added = ['hypr1005.ops.colo.cmp.com,web1234.ads.colo.cmp.com,876543,4']
```

The above variable is a list and it contains single value which is seperated by comma, i just want to split the values using comma and to create a list which looks like

```
added = ['hypr1005.ops.colo.cmp.com','web1234.ads.colo.cmp.com','876543','4']

words = added.split(',')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Guess split works only on string not on list, so how can i do this?

Answer (score 2):

Call `split` method of the first item of the list (`added[0]`):

```
>>> added = ['hypr1005.ops.colo.cmp.com,web1234.ads.colo.cmp.com,876543,4']
>>> added = added[0].split(',')
>>> added
['hypr1005.ops.colo.cmp.com', 'web1234.ads.colo.cmp.com', '876543', '4']
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to use split, it should be a string.

```
>>> added = "'hypr1005.ops.colo.cmp.com','web1234.ads.colo.cmp.com','876543','4'"
>>> words = added.split(',')
>>> words
["'hypr1005.ops.colo.cmp.com'", "'web1234.ads.colo.cmp.com'", "'876543'", "'4'"]
>>>
```